# Android app activity button timeout selection

Tags: java, android, timeout

I have a basic android app using the zxing scanner and an activity with 3 buttons. The scanner sends a code to the activity, and the user can choose to clock in, clock out, or cancel the operation. This works fine. I want to add an auto timeout to this process, so that if the user does not click a button in a specific time period, the system will determine if they are in or out (cancel button must be pressed). I have the logic for all of this, but I don't know how to add the timeout logic. There is the initial layout, the activity Java code, the SQLite database object and handler, the zxing integration, and an ASync post. I have included the main java class below, which includes the onClick event and primary integration between zxing and the SQLite (those are omitted).

Any thoughts on how I could implement a basic timeout? I would like a function to be called from the main java class if a button is not pressed, and this function will determine (based on the last selection) if they are in or out.

Thanks for any help or suggestions you can provide.

### Main Java Class

```
package com.neonet.neonetjobcardscanner;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.neonet.neonetjobcardscanner.R;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
// remove before launch
public class ClockInOut extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnInitListener {
    private Button btnClockIn;
    private Button btnClockOut;
    private Button btnCancel;
    private String employee;
    private String operation;
    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator;
    private neonetpost post;
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM, new Locale("en", "EN"));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_clock_in_out);
        btnClockIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClockIn);
        btnClockOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClockOut);
        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnClockIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnClockOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan(); // optional scan type can be passed here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.clock_in_out, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        post = new neonetpost();
        String result = null;
        String in = null;
        String confirmation = null;
        String now = df.format(new Date());
        try {
            SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btnClockIn) {
                in = "true";
                if (operation != null)
                    confirmation = getString(R.string.ttsJobIn);
                else
                    confirmation = getString(R.string.ttsClockIn);
                Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting...");
                db.addTimeclockEntry(new TimeclockEntry(Integer.valueOf(employee), now, "IN"));
            } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnClockOut) {
                in = "false";
                if (operation != null)
                    confirmation = getString(R.string.ttsJobOut);
                else
                    confirmation = getString(R.string.ttsClockOut);

                db.addTimeclockEntry(new TimeclockEntry(Integer.valueOf(employee), now, "OUT"));
            } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnCancel) {
            }

            db.close();
            db.exportDB(getApplicationContext());
            if (in != null) {
                post.execute(employee, operation, in);
                while (result == null) {
                    result = post.result();
                }
                tts.speak(confirmation + " " + (operation!=null?result:""), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
            employee = operation = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e != null) {
                StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
                Log.e("JobCardScanner",
                        "ClockInOut.java onclick(): " + String.format(e.toString() + "%n" + errors.toString()));
            }
        }

        if (post.hasError())
            Log.e("JobCardScanner", "ClockInOut.java onclick(): " + (result == null ? "NULL" : result));
        else
            Log.i("JobCardScanner", "ClockInOut.java onClick(): " + (result == null ? "NULL" : result));

        scanIntegrator.initiateScan(); // optional scan type can be passed here
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        try {
            // retrieve scan result
            IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            if (scanningResult != null) {
                // we have a result
                final String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
                // String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
                if (scanContent.indexOf("E") > -1) {
                    employee = scanContent.substring(2);
                    if (operation == null) {
                        btnClockIn.setText(R.string.btnClockIn);
                        btnClockOut.setText(R.string.btnClockOut);
                    } else {
                        btnClockIn.setText(R.string.btnOperationStart);
                        btnClockOut.setText(R.string.btnOperationEnd);
                    }
                } else if (scanContent.indexOf("OP:") > -1) {
                    operation = scanContent.substring(3) + getString(R.string.operation_separator);
                    tts.speak(getString(R.string.ttsJobScan), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
                }

                Log.i("JobCardScanner",
                        "ClockInOut.java onActivityResult(): Received " + scanContent);
            } else {
                Log.i("JobCardScanner", "ClockInOut.java onActivityResult(): No scan data received");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e != null) {
                StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
                Log.e("JobCardScanner", "ClockInOut.java onActivityResult(): " + String.format(e.toString() + "%n" + errors.toString()));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int arg0) {
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }
}
```

### Main Activity Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.neonet.neonetjobcardscanner.ClockInOut" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txtClockInOut"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClockIn"
        style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/button_min_height"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/button_min_width"
        android:text="@string/btnClockIn"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClockOut"
        style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnClockIn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/button_min_height"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/button_min_width"
        android:text="@string/btnClockOut"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnClockOut"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/button_min_height"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/button_min_width"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/btnCancel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### Main Activity Layout [Graphical]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSL5c.png

Comment: I believe the Timer() class can do what I want, based on this blog post:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/12/example-of-using-timer-and-timertask-on.html

I will continue with this and see if it works. If anyone has a better idea, or knows of an issue I will run into and can help, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The Timer() class and subsequent examples did exactly what was needed!

Reference:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/12/example-of-using-timer-and-timertask-on.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html